# How to pad CSV file missing columns

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql, shell, csv

I have a problem with some CSV files comming from a soft and that I want to use to make PostgreSQL import (function COPY FROM CSV). The problem is that some last columns are missing like this (letter for headers, number for values, _ for the TAB delimiter):

```
a_b_c_d
1_2_3_4
5_6_7       <- last column missing
8_9_0_1
2_6_7       <- last column missing
```

COPY in_my_table FROM file.csv  result is :
**ERROR:  missing data for column "d"**

Sample of a correct file for import :

```
a_b_c_d
1_2_3_4
5_6_7_       <- null column but not missing
8_9_0_1
2_6_7_       <- null column but not missing
```

My question : is there some commands in bash / linux shell to add the TAB delimiter to make a correct / comlete / padded csv file with all columns.

Thanks for help.

Comment: you can copy csv to one column table and then insert into my_table from it delimited data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so in fact I found this:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'NF=50' input.csv > output.csv
```

where 50 is the number of TAB + 1.

Comment: On mac, use `gawk` (install from brew) instead of built-in `awk`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't knew much about linux but this could be easily done in postgresql via simple command like

```
copy tableName from '/filepath/name.csv' delimiter '_' csv WITH NULL AS 'null';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of sed and regular expressions:

```
sed -r 's/^[0-9](_[0-9]){2}$/\0_/g' file.csv
```

You only need to replace `_` by your delimiter (`\t`).

Answer (score 1):

Awk is good for this.

```
awk -F"\t" '{     # Tell awk we are working with tabs
if ($4 =="")      # If the last field is empty
    print $0"\t"  # print the whole line with a tab
else
    print $0      # Otherwise just print the line
}' your.csv  > your.fixed.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl has a [CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~ishigaki/Text-CSV-1.94/lib/Text/CSV.pm) module, which might be handy to fix even more complicated CSV errors. On my Ubuntu test system it is part of the package `libtext-csv-perl`.

This fixes your problem:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({ binary => 1, eol => $/, sep_char => '_' });

open my $broken, '<', 'broken.csv';
open my $fixed, '>', 'fixed.csv';

while (my $row = $csv->getline ($broken)) {
  $#{$row} = 3;
  $csv->print ($fixed, $row);
}
```

Change `sep_char` to `"\t"`, if you have a tabulator delimited file and keep in mind that Perl treats `"\t"` and `'\t'` differently.